# Pass scope of one controller to another in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When I click a button in `myCtrl` controller. The `ng-model` of `myCtrl2` should also be changed with `ng-model` of current controller:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="name">
     <button ng-click="just()">submit</button>
</div>
<div  ng-controller="myCtrl2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name2">
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name="before";
    $scope.just = function()
    {
       $scope.name="after";

       $scope.name2="after";   /////  this is not working


    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Add watch to listen changes or broadcast from rootscope.

Answer (score 3):

There are several way to solve this. One of them is using $emit event. You can dig about it deeper [here.](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

But for quick reference, I provide you a [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JegGGmCy33qcOwBSy2UQ?p=preview). Please check it out.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
   $scope.name="before";
   $scope.just = function(){
      $scope.name="after";
      $rootScope.$emit('update');
   }
   }).controller('myCtrl2', function($rootScope, $scope){
      $rootScope.$on('update', function(){
      $scope.name2 = "after";
   })
});
```

Comment: Yes you're welcome. So please mark this as the accepted answer to help people who face the same situation as you had, in the future. Thans.. :)

Comment: HOW TO ACCEPT THIS ANSWER

Comment: There should be a check icon in the left side of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a service which you would then inject into your controllers.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

you can use $rootScope for this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
   $scope.name="before";
   $scope.just = function(){
      $scope.name="after";
      $rootScope.nameInRootScope=$scope.name;
   }
   }).controller('myCtrl2', function($rootScope, $scope){
      $scope.name2 = $rootScope.nameInRootScope;
   })
});
```